# Is there any way we can run multiple roles with a particular user in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

Is there any way we can run multiple roles with a particular sudo  user using Ansible. If yes how can i do it .

ansible 2.7.5

Comment: Edit your answer so to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use a [playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html#working-with-playbooks). For example:

```
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: particular_sudo_user
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  roles:
     - role01
     - role02
```